# Objectify Query an Entity Throws a key load error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I wrote a simple query with Google Cloud Datastore objectify.

```
Query<ChatFeedbackEntity> query = ObjectifyService.ofy().load()
                           .type(ChatFeedbackEntity.class);
```

Testing with App Engine Datastore localhost emulator throws a keyload exception. I want all the queries to be processed at once regardless of the key/ ID. Is there a workaround around this?